# frequency of 'special-prime' gaps

Tags: number-theory

For convenience of reference, let me define special primes to be those primes, which remain prime when their rightmost digit is removed. It is observed that the gaps between 2 consecutive special primes increases. However, 6 is the most frequent special-prime gap(i checked upto 10^6). How can we explain this on the basis of current prime distribution theorems?

Comment: Look into "[jumping champions](http://primes.utm.edu/glossary/xpage/JumpingChampion.html)" for the set of all primes: 6 is the most frequent gap for a long time, but eventually it will be overtaken by 30 and then later by other gaps. I suspect the same will happen to these special primes.

Comment: Which is more common, 10P+1,10P+7 or 10P+3,10P+9?

Comment: 10n+3 and 10n+9 are the 2 most common special primes as per my data upto 10^7, which explains why it is 6, but is there a reason why those 2 are the most common?

Answer (score 1):

Let the primes be $P,Q,10P+a,10Q+b$.
If $P\neq Q$, then all four numbers must be prime.   If $P=Q$, only three numbers must be prime.  That gives an advantage to single-digit differences.
$a$ and $b$ must be 1,3,7 or 9.  If 1 or 7 is involved, then $P$ or $Q$ cannot be one less than a multiple of 3.  That gives an advantage to $3$ and $9$.
So a difference of six, which is $(10P+9)-(10P+3)$, has these advantages.

Comment: Then are you saying 3n-1 is the most frequent prime form ?

Comment: No, but it removes half the available primes.

Comment: i guess that explains most of it.